Setting Up a Single-Node Kafka Server on a Local Network
I need some help with setting up a single-node Kafka server. I've followed the official Kafka documentation to set it up, and it's working on my local machine. Now, I need other nodes on the local network to be able to connect to the Kafka server. To make the Kafka server accessible within the local network, I've modified the configuration file as follows:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.5.155:9092

After making these changes, I was able to create topics and use both the producer and consumer on the local machine without any issues. However, when I try to simulate the producer and consumer on another server using a Python 3 script, I encounter problems.
Here’s the producer script:
from kafka3 import KafkaProducer
import json

# Create Kafka Producer instance
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers='192.168.5.155:9092',  # Address and port of the Kafka server
    value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')  # Serialize messages to JSON format
)

# Send a message to Kafka's topic
producer.send('test-topic', {'key': 'value'})  # Replace 'test-topic' with your actual topic name

# Ensure all messages are sent
producer.flush()

print("Message sent successfully")

And here’s the consumer script:
from kafka3 import KafkaConsumer
import json


# Create Kafka Consumer instance
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'test-topic',  # Replace with your actual topic name
    bootstrap_servers='192.168.5.155:9092',  # Address and port of the Kafka server
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',  # Start reading from the earliest message
    enable_auto_commit=True,  # Automatically commit offsets
    group_id='my-group',  # Consumer group ID
    value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8'))  # Deserialize messages from JSON format
)

# Consume messages

for message in consumer:
print(f"Received message: {message.value}")

When I run these scripts, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/root/python_code/writing.py", line 5, in <module>producer = KafkaProducer(File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kafka3/producer/kafka.py", line 383, in initclient = self.config['kafka_client'](File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kafka3/client_async.py", line 244, in initself.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kafka3/client_async.py", line 900, in check_versionraise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()kafka3.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable 

I’m wondering where I might have gone wrong. The script was generated using ChatGPT-4. I tried telnet 192.168.5.155 9092, but the connection failed, even though I’ve already disabled the firewall. I also checked, and there is a port listening on 9092.
I tried to ping 192.168.5.155, and the network is reachable. I also checked the port status using a command, which returned the following:
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                 \*:9092             *:*  


Ping;netcat doesn't test kafka protocol. Use kcat... Did you restart the broker after modifying the settings?
